# How To Effectively Dense Rank Groups in a Table Using Powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have been trying the easiest method to dense rank the following data for data having groups or category. I have ask similiar question for ranking a data, but this one is for data with grouping.

I wish to rank the scores column as shown below, such that the highest number take 1st position=1st. The second largest number takes the second position etc.
Where there are ties, give them same ranking order. say score=200 of ID=3002, ID=3010 occurring twice is placed 1st for the class SS3. So in this case the scorers will have the same ranking => Dense Ranking. same thing goes for all the classes.

The Class represent group of formations.
Each individual, would be graded per each class.
All methods have google, seems cumbersome and somehow takes more of powerquery memory space.

| Scores | ID | Class | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 130 | 1002 | SS1 |  |
| 180 | 2003 | SS2 |  |
| 140 | 1006 | SS1 |  |
| 130 | 1007 | SS1 |  |
| 200 | 3002 | SS3 |  |
| 200 | 3010 | SS3 |  |

Expected results

| Scores | ID | Class | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 130 | 1002 | SS1 | 2nd |
| 180 | 2003 | SS2 | 1st |
| 140 | 1006 | SS1 | 1st |
| 130 | 1007 | SS1 | 2nd |
| 200 | 3002 | SS3 | 1st |
| 200 | 3010 | SS3 | 1st |
| 100 | 3007 | SS3 | 2nd |
| 80 | 3045 | SS3 | 3rd |

The challenge is how do I achieve this using powerquery.

Comment: With DAX this would be plain vanilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table.AddRankColumn(#"Added Index", "Rank", {"Scores", Order.Descending}, [RankKind = RankKind.Dense])
```

Depending on your version, you may need to add this in M Code, or it may be seen as an option in the Power Query menu bar.

Also note that the result will be to also sort the table in rank order. So you may need to add an index column to be able to sort it back to your original order.

Here is an example using your data:

***Code edited to Group by Class before adding the Rank column***

```
let

//Read in the original table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Scores"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Scores", Int64.Type}, {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Class", type text}}),

//add Index column to be able to return to original order
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Group by class
//  then add rank column to each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Class"}, {
        {"Rank", each Table.AddRankColumn(_, "Rank", {"Scores", Order.Descending}, [RankKind=RankKind.Dense]) }}),

//expand the grouped tables
    #"Expanded Rank" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Rank", {"Scores", "ID", "Index", "Rank"}),

//Sort back to original order
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Rank",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),

//remove Index column and re-order the columns as desired
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Scores", "ID", "Class", "Rank"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

*Notes:*

- *You can easily write a custom function to output the rank as ordinal vs cardinal numbers.*

***Edit:***
  *if `Table.AddRankColumn` not available*

- Add Custom function as blank query
- Rename the blank query per the comments

```
//Rename fnRankDense

(t as table)=>

let 
    tbl = Table.Buffer(t),

//Group by Scores
    group = Table.Group(tbl, {"Scores"}, {
        {"grouped", each _, type table[ID=Int64.Type, Class=text, Index=Int64.Type]}
    }),

//Sort by Scores descending
    sort = Table.Sort(group,{"Scores", Order.Descending}),

//add index column for ranking
    #"Add Rank Column" = Table.AddIndexColumn(sort,"Rank",1),

//Expand the table
    #"Expanded Rank" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Add Rank Column", "grouped", {"ID", "Class", "Index"})

in 
    #"Expanded Rank"
```

***New M Code***
*to use with custom function*

```
let

//Read in the original table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Scores"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Scores", Int64.Type}, {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Class", type text}}),

//add Index column to be able to return to original order
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Group by class
//   Aggregate using custom function to generate dense rank scores
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Class"}, {{"all", 
        each fnRankDense(_), type table [Scores=nullable number, ID=nullable number, Class=nullable text, Index=number, Rank=number]}}),

//Expand the grouped columns and set in desired order
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "all", {"Scores", "ID", "Index", "Rank"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded all",{"Scores", "ID", "Class", "Index", "Rank"}),

//Sort rows back to original order and delete index column
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: thank you. buh, second row from the solution table has an error. The class SS2, Is a different academic class,and as such ID=2003, with score=180 should be rank 1,

Comment: thank you. buh, second row from the solution table has an error. The class SS2, Is a different academic class,and as such ID=2003, with score=180 should be rank 1.                                      Two student scored 200  in class=SS3, so there Rank is tied=1.                                                                       In Class SS1:   Student ID:1002 AND 1006 & 1007 had score 130, 140 and 130   respectively.so their rank should be: 2nd, 1st, 2nd.

Comment: @val I missed that part where you wanted it grouped by class.  Simple fix to just move the AddRankColumn function into a custom aggregation in the Table.Group function.  See the changes in my updated post.

Comment: Thank you, it works buh not for old version of excel. Table.AddRankColumn is a new function

Comment: @val I think some corporate versions of PQ have not yet been updated. If working without the `Table.AddRankColumn` is important, I'd replace it with a custom function.  I'll edit my question to show that.

Comment: This method works perfectly well.Thank you.   Please, one more question. what if i have several columns, how am  i going handle this , in the custom function                       #"Expanded Rank" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Add Rank Column", "grouped", {"ID", "Class", "Index"})..... i wish to  expand it to  whatever the table headers from previous step,instead of manually entering the field headers for the the table, is it practicable?

Comment: @val Yes, you would create a `List` of the column headers using `Table.ColumnNames`, removing any columns you don't want to expand, and then use that list as the columns argument for `Table.ExpandTableColumn`.  Do a search for `Power Query expand table column dynamically` and you'll find the method laid out there.  Suggest you post a new question if you can't figure out how to incorporate it into the code.

Comment: Ronsefeld,  i have tried it buh, this is what i get.An error occurred in the ‘’ query. Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Table.
Details:
    Value=List
    Type=Type                                                                                                                                Have open a new trend on that:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73696139/how-to-expand-dynamically-column-headers-when-using-a-custom-function-dense-ran/73696354#73696354