# How To expand Dynamically, Column Headers When Using A Custom Function Dense Ranks of Groups in Powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am stuck at expanding columns dynamically, following this trend i created here in this platform
See
:[How To Effectively Dense Rank Groups in a Table Using Powerquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73680958/how-to-effectively-dense-rank-groups-in-a-table-using-powerquery/73682112?noredirect=1#comment130131224_73682112).

Now, intend to expand column dynamically, because, some of the dataset, in real life suituation, have huge numbers of columns, and manually entering the column names ,takes time and boring in order to take care of other column names.
Secondly, if my dataset changes either by api,or  by a change of column names, then , i run into error.how could i handle this challenge

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the column you want to expand is named **custom** and has a bunch of tables in it, you can use below to expand all the columns in that column

```
ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere", "Custom"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
#"ExpandedThem" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere", "Custom",ColumnsToExpand ,ColumnsToExpand )
```

Comment: tried it, buy saying can't convert data type of type list to a table? I don't know why?    This was the  trend I initiated.The solution of Dense rank was provided by Ron Ronsefied.   How To Effectively Dense Rank Groups in a Table Using Powerquery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73680958/how-to-effectively-dense-rank-groups-in-a-table-using-powerquery/73682112?noredirect=1#comment130131224_73682112

Comment: Buy the problem is that when I have  many columns ,how do I dynamically add this columns in power query .  I need assistance her.pls!